# ejabberd : federating with yahoo error 404

Tags: xmpp, jabber, ejabberd

After I installed **ejabberd** I am able to federate with google, but I can not federate with yahoo and AIM ...
I wounder if someone can show me the way.

Comment: ejabberd is a jabber server from the Raspberian distro.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting your XMPP server to AIM, you'd have to use and configure transports. I'd recommend [Spectrum](http://spectrum.im/).